# OSMdroid : How to load offline map from zip archive - MapTileFileArchiveProvider

Tags: android, dictionary, archive, offline, osmdroid

I really need some help with the OSMdroid library. It is useful to have maps stored in sdcard as zip files. Also, maps can be unzipped and the image files may be used directly for faster rendering.

I managed to load tiles from my sdcard  when the tiles are *unziiped*, have *.tile extension* and are *stored* in the folder */sdcard/osmdroid/tiles/Mapnik/...* 
To create my map I used the *Mobile Atlas Creator* and *OSMAND tile storage* format.

I read some tutorials on the web that claim storing zip files containing tiles are stored in */sdcard/osmdroid* then the offline map will be loaded from the zip. But it does not work for me.

1. Did anybody managed to make it work? If so how?
2. Do I need to instantiate my own MapTileFileArchiveProvider? If so, how can I do that? Any examples?

Comment: Hey, can u post 2 simple samples - 1 for storing the map and 1 for retrieving it?

Comment: can you provide the sample code :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The files in your ZIP need to be in the form of:

```
Z/X/Y.png
```

If you rename your Y.tile files to Y.png, zip them up and put the zip file in /sdcard/osmdroid/, that should work.

Comment: Sorry my hasty asnwer. I am doing further testing and I 'll share the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The map tiles are rendered properly.
If anyone is interested, the OSMdroid ZIP format of the Mobile Atlas Creator can be used to create such a zipped map.

Comment: @user976933 - Doesn't the zip need to go in /sdcard/osmdroid/tiles? I have actually tried it in both places and I still get a blank map.

Comment: @DavidDoria could you manage to solve this?? I'm stuck exactly here

Comment: @epiGR Could you show the snippet to set the tile source.

Comment: @ArjunIssar sorry, this was a long time ago. If I had figured it out I would have replied back then :(

Answer (score 0):

Just a correction or addition to the answer of user976933, the zip should also contain the name of the tilesource as base directory, the needed structure inside the zip is:

tilesourcename/Z/X/Y

The code loading the tiles is in BitmapTileSourceBase:

```
@Override
public String getTileRelativeFilenameString(final MapTile tile) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(pathBase());
    sb.append('/');
    sb.append(tile.getZoomLevel());
    sb.append('/');
    sb.append(tile.getX());
    sb.append('/');
    sb.append(tile.getY());
    sb.append(imageFilenameEnding());
    return sb.toString();
}

public String pathBase() {
    return mName;
}
```