# OSMdroid : How to render offline map from a local zip archive

Tags: android, dictionary, offline-mode, php-ziparchive, osmdroid

I'm using the osmdroid library for  my custom map application and my last issue is related to the accessibility of offline contents prepared in a common format easy to share.

In the specific I'm now able to correctly download .png tiles from my custom data source using *Tile Packager* and compress them into a .zip archive directly on the SD card, but I can't render them in my MapView. Could someone please post some example to explain how to load the tiles directly from the zip archive in a scenario without connectivity in offline mode?

I already checked the post [OSMdroid : How to load offline map from zip archive - MapTileFileArchiveProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634148/osmdroid-how-to-load-offline-map-from-zip-archive-maptilefilearchiveprovider), but no example is provided.

Comment: can this be done by storing tiles in an external sdcard?

Answer (score 1):

you should use MOBAC to download tiles and select map format as OSMdroid Zip... then just place that .zip file in /sdcard/osmdroid/