# OsmDroid show blank screen with blocks

Tags: android, osmdroid

Am trying to use OsmDroid with MapQuest maps downloaded from Mobile Atlas Creator.
I followed all the instructions to generate the map tiles, upload them to the SDcard etc but when I run this on the device I get a screen with a bunch of empty boxes... What am I doing wrong?

```
> @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.osm_map);
>         mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
>         mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
>         mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
>         mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
>         mapController = mapView.getController();
>         mapController.setZoom(15);
>     }
>     protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         return false;
>     }
```

Comment: Where did you put the files on SD-card. Need exact folder location to your first tile.

Comment: /mtn/sdcard/osmdroid/MapquestOSM.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a post covering the same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7636905/969325). If that doesn't work you can try [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13864750/969325) which is a little more complex but has the advantage that you can put the zip in any folder you'd like.

Comment: Location need to be under the sd card: /sdcard/osmdroid/tiles/MapquestOSM/15/X/X.png

Comment: @Lennie Why are the tiles that are downloaded during online use called /sdcard/osmdroid/tiles/MapquestOSM/15/X/X.png.tile (an additional .tile extension to the .png)?